# Ubuntu 20.04.4 Installation Error

Tags: boot, usb-installation

I am trying to install ubuntu and get rid if Windows. I created my bootable USB stick and when I restart to install I get the screen that says Ubuntu and all of those options but after a few seconds I get this screen and my computer locks up and starts to heat up.

[image: Picture of Error Code]

I am not sure what to do as I am not "code" savvy (yet).

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the brand and model of computer you're trying to install Ubuntu onto? Errors like this may be related to UEFI configurations, but a make and model will help confirm this.